# Gzip compressing multiple files with subfolders into each name using batch and 7zip

Tags: windows, batch-file, gzip, 7zip, gunzip

I have a folder which contains subfolders with multiple html files in it. I want to compress all html files by its own to gzip, step by step, in every subfolder with a 7zip batch (.bat). I dont need to keep the original files.

How it looks like right now:

```
Example[Mainfolder]

ny [subfolder]
test1.html
test2.html

oh [subfolder]
test3.html
test4.html
...
```

How it should look like:

```
Example[Mainfolder]
Batch File

ny [subfolder]
test1.html.gz
test2.html.gz

oh [subfolder]
test3.html.gz
test4.html.gz
...
```

Im no developer and i hope anybody can help me. I am using Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 2):

I created a code:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.html) do c:\programme\7-zip\7z.exe a -tgzip "%%i.gz" "%%i"
pause
```

But i wonder how to include all subfolders? I found this:

```
-r:          traverse all subdirectories
```

But i dont know where to place the "-r". The above code is not working anymore when i place it in it.

***PS: Thanks for downvoting my question...***

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Cant make it work with the -r